# CSS @media rule for ultra wide screens

Tags: javascript, css, font-size

Hello everyone my site is

[El Paso Texas Web Design and Graphic Design | Desert Sun Studio](https://www.desertsunstudio.com)

there are 2 media rules

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px){

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){

}
```

essentially these two render my site correctly on mobile and on any 16:9 monitor..however i use vw for font sizes so ultra wide monitors are suffering

i was wondering if there was a css or js fix to make the font sizes turn to a max px size

i was trying

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1800px){

}
```

but this disturbs display on larger screens such as tv and i like that it maintained its 16:9 ratio.

i was wondering if anyone used something like

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1800px) and (max-height: 1000px){

}
```

Comment: Consider using `vmin` instead of `vw`.